# Rails: Why does my server redirect http to https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a rails app that I had built on Heroku and I had configured it to use SSL there. Now I'm moving to AWS EC2 and I want to get a version of my app working without SSL. Once that is done I will add the SSL functionality later.

My stack is Puma + Nginx + PostgreSQL and I'm working with Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.2.3 and Capistrano 3.4.0.

I remember in my app that I had once inserted the line

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

in config/environments/production.rb. I commented this out expecting my app to go back to working well with http. But it didn't: even after commenting that line, whenever I visit my EC2 public IP (52.35.82.113) the request gets sent on port 80 (http) and gets redirected to port 443 (https).

This can be seen more clearly when I run `curl -v http://localhost` on my EC2 instance it returns:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 12:22:56 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://localhost/
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I'm not very experienced when it comes to this stuff. I thought initially the problem would be with my Nginx configuration, in my previous question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/742611/aws-ec2-instance-public-ip-doesnt-load) it was suggested to me that there was nothing wrong with my Nginx config and that the redirect was coming from Rails. I suspect this is the case since I can't see anything in Nginx that could be enforcing the redirect, but if you think the issue might be there then you can see a lot of the relevant code in the link above.

What else in Rails apart from the force_ssl printed above could be causing the redirect?

Thanks for your help everyone. Let me know if you have any questions or need more info!

Comment: I guess on your nginx configuration you've done the force ssl.

Comment: Have you ever restarted your Puma server?

Comment: Hi @Tobias. Yes, I'm using `ps` to find the process id and restarting it with `kill -s SIGUSR2 <pid>`

Comment: Dennis, do you develop the code on a local machine? If so, how is it served there?

Comment: @gf_ Yes, I run `rails server` which boots up puma which says things like `=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000` and `* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000`, then I ask my browser to look for `localhost:3000` and the website runs as intended

Comment: Are you using any proxy_cache directives on your nginx config files? I wonder if nginx is caching that response. Now this is a complete stretch, but you can try to add a `proxy_no_cache true`; right above your proxy_pass directive. Don't forget to restart nginx after that.

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim The nginx config is to be found [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/742611/aws-ec2-instance-public-ip-doesnt-load); no `proxy_cache` involved.

Answer (score 8):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/victorlamhk/7019359) suggests it might be because of an HSTS header:

> So if you enabled force_ssl once, even [if] you change the config value to false later, the browser you used to open you[r] app before will still remember this website (using domain to identify) [and] require [you] to use HTTPS, and redirect you to HTTPS connection automatically.

According to [this page](http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers) you can remove your HSTS entries by going to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` in Chrome and `about:permissions` in Firefox and deleting `~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist` in Safari.

Comment: This is the exact problem I had, and the solution for Chrome (per that link; consider editing your answer to include it) is to go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and delete the domain from HSTS.

Comment: I added some instructions on removing HSTS entries.

Comment: Hoooooooly crap thank you. What an absolute nightmare that was.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails you can force site wide SSL using a config file(like you were doing) or you can pick which endpoints will use SSL and use the `force_ssl` class method at the controller level.

Maybe you used that method on your `application_controller.rb` or which ever controller is serving the root path and forgot about it. You may find an exemple of such mechanism within Rails docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html

> force_ssl(options = {}) Link Force the request to this particular
>   controller or specified actions to be under HTTPS protocol.
>
> If you need to disable this for any reason (e.g. development) then you
>   can use an :if or :unless condition.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?

  def ssl_configured?
    !Rails.env.development?
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @alexandre-angelim, that's a really good call but unfortunately no, there's nothing like that in my application controller or my 'main' controller that serves the root path. I've also tried looking in my config/routes.rb but there is nothing there that would do it either

Answer (score 2):

I tried before to comment this line in production server and it didn't change anything so instead of commenting just change true to false like:

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

Comment: Hi @marouenB, this was also a really good shout. I tried it but it didn't seem to change anything. I feel like there was a lot going wrong with my configs generally though so I couldn't really tell. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Solution for me was:

1. Delete **config.force_ssl = true** from aplication.rb
2. For ubuntu **Ctrl + Shift + Del** => Clear browsing data

Comment: Setting config.force_ssl = false && deleting browser cache worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem too (rails + puma + nginx). Every `redirect_to` was sent to `https`, even if coming from `http`.

In the `vhost.conf` there was this line:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

`redirect_to` worked properly after changing that to

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
```

Comment: Never would've thought to look here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in my case this setting in nginx config was the reason of issue
`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;`

make sure that your config does not contain same setting